# How to filter a table name in Extended Events?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I created an Extended Event Session using a script with a Where clause in order to filter commands which refers to a table whose name is MySchema.MyTable:

```
WHERE ([sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%MySchema.MyTbl%'))
```

The problem is that the table can appear in one of the 4 following ways:

```
MySchema.MyTable

[MySchema].MyTable

MySchema.[MyTable]

[MySchema].[MyTable]
```

I can create a long Where clause with al those options and the "Or" operator between them (a to find a good solution to the ambiguity of the characters ],[), but it is not very elegant.
I wish I could use Replace operator in order to remove those characters (],[) but I don't know how..
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I think a good solution would be to filter by the object_id instead of by manipulating the SQL string in order to find the object name