# MS SQL Server monitoring table locks

Tags: sql, sql-server, table-locking

I would like to ask whether there's some kind of a mechanism that would allow me to monitor, capture and write (e.g. to a table) information about table locks that occured.

What I found so far are few stored procedures that can be executed manually or periodically, what I actually need is to be able to catch them before/within the insert (more likely update) and save to another table.

I ask this question, because I have a stored procedure to update data in one of the tables from my database and normally it is executed between 30 and 50ms. But once a time weird thing is happening and it takes up to 90s to execute the same procedure, using the same data and same server cofiguration.

Should I use a trigger for this? If yes, what trigger should I set it up at? I only need table locks for a certain table. Since from what I understand, shared lock will not allow inserts / updates and therefore I need all kind of locks to be captured.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked into extended events? Your task sounds like suitable for that

Comment: You can use "with(nolock)" to select query.

Comment: Mukash I don't want to get rid of locks, I have way too many selects and unfortunately it's a legacy code with dsql spread all around. I need to identify what query locks the whole table and for how long. @JamesZ thank you, I had a quick look at it, but I can't set it up properly, Is there any way to filter the data to only capture table locks for a specific table?

Comment: By the way, can I somehow select things from that extended events? I would like to get lock time, I took two events (lock_aquired and lock_released) and filtered them myself, now I need to find out how long the locks persisted and identify those that were too long.

Comment: At least based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835678/how-to-filter-a-table-name-in-extended-events you should probably filter by object_id. I have never tried to monitor locks with extended events myself

Comment: @JamesZ I'd love to use object_id, but that would mean I must change the filters for each database I'll use it at (since object_id will be different for each database). Well, I could handle that myself, but... I would have to know how to "query" this session to obtain certain information, possibly with sql so I could use WHERE clause. I do found out that lock_released has duration value returned, so that solves the need for calculating duration myself.